# How find filename starts with letter and save it to variable and save it to var?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I need to write a line in bash which will find file that starts with letter "T" in specified folder and save it to $VAR.

Let's assume that `C:/workspace/` has one file that starts with letter "T".

I need to find that file and save its name to variable.

Honestly, that's all I managed to create. I do not know how to create it. I think I need to use sed to do it.

```
FILE_PATH='C:/workspace/'T.*'' | sed "s/.*\///"
echo "$FILE_PATH"
```

Answer (score 2):

you mean something like that?

```
var=$(find /path/to/special/folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "T*" -printf "%f\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

I just used ls

```
TFileName=`ls T*`
```

and then after pipe I concat filename with sed at my discretion